# Eloquent Relationships (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm making a **Laravel 5.4** application, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I should structure my data with **eloquent relationships**.

This is my models and how I want them to be related:

- **School** → Has classes, users and events
- **User** → Can belong to a school. Can have classes and sessions (with cases)
- **Class** → Belongs to a school. Has users and subjects. Can have homework
- **Subject** → Belongs to a class
- **Session** → Belongs to a user. Can have cases
- **Case** → Belongs to a session
- **Event** → Belongs to a school
- **Homework** → Belongs to a class

How should I structure this with eloquent relation functions (belongsTo, hasMany and so on) in my Laravel 5.4 project?

Comment: How would you do it without eloquent? Have you tried to write down the database structure?

Comment: You already know the relationships. It should be easy to do it in Laravel if you read the [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) documentation on Laravel.

Comment: The main problem is that I don't know when I should use the "hasManyThrough" relation. Could someone explain when to use this?

Comment: @KristofferDamborgJørgensen Probably not. For two reasons: (1) It is not what you ask in your question and (2) it is a broad question. Plus, you should keep it stupid simple, go with the other relationships if you understand them more, it should do the trick for what you asked.

Comment: @Wistar - Makes a lot of sense to keep it stupid simple :D How about foreign keys (like user_id etc.), do I need to add them myself, or does eloquent do that for me? :)

Comment: @KristofferDamborgJørgensen It depends how you name them. Look at the documentation and try to match the naming. Run it. If you dont match the naming, then add foreign keys. If it does not work, come back with a question on exactly what you tried, what does not work and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, this help a lot. Just another question. If I don't want every user to belong to a school, which kind of relationship should I then have for user <--> school?

Comment: @KristofferDamborgJørgensen still a belongsTo relation, but leave the school_id null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Class, User and Event models has a property school_id and the primary key you ant to use is id of the respective model, your Class, User, Event and School models should look like as follow.

School

```
class School extends Model
{
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function classes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
}

public function sessions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
}
}
```

User

```
class User extends Model
{
public function school(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}

public function classes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
}

public function events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
}
```

Class

```
class Class extends Model
{
public function school(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function subjects(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
}
public function homeworks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Homework');
}
}
```

Event

```
class Class extends Model
{
public function school(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}

}
```

You can use these relationships to define queries with chaining capability. e.g. if you want to get all the events associated with a School that has a id property equals to $id you can write,

```
$events = App\School::find($id)->events;
```

Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) explains it well

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is

**SCHOOL**

```
public function classes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

**CLASS**

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}

public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
}

public function homeworks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Homework');
}


public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','class_users','class_id','user_id');
    // this should be many to many because users can also have many classes
}
```

**USER**

```
public function school()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}

public function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Class','class_users','user_id','class_id');
    // this should be many to many as explained to class
}

public function sessions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Session','session_users','user_id','session_id');
    // like classes do, this should be many to many relationship because sessions can also have many users
}
```

**SUBJECT**

```
public function class()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Class');
}
```

**SESSION**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','session_users','session_id','user_id');
    // should be many to many as well
}

public function cases()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Case');
}
```

**CASE**

```
public function session()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Session');
}
```

**EVENT**

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
}
```

**HOMEWORK**

```
public function class()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Class');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the School model and underlying table created, it’s time to create the relation. Open the School model and create a public method named classes, users and events; inside it referencing the hasMany method:

School :

```
class School extends Model {

  public function classes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
  }
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
  public function events()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
  }

}
```

User :

```
class User extends Model {

    public function school(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }

    public function classes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
    }

    public function sessions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
    }

}
```

Class :

```
class Class extends Model {

    public function school(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
    }

    public function homeworks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Homework');
    }

}
```

Subject :

```
class Subject extends Model {

    public function class(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Class');
    }

}
```

Session:

```
class Session extends Model {

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function cases(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Case');
    }

}
```

Case :

```
class Case extends Model {

    public function session(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Session');
    }

}
```

Event :

```
class Event extends Model {

    public function school(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }

}
```

Homework:

```
class Homework extends Model {

    public function class(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Class');
    }

}
```

For more details of hasMany relationship, Please check the link here : [EasyLaravelBook](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/25/creating-a-hasmany-relation-in-laravel-5/)

Comment: user should belongsToMany Classes as classes can also have many users .. this should be pivoted by a table .. as well as to sessions